# How to use Principal Propagation to call Workflow REST APIs

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Is it possible to use Principal Propagation to call Workflow REST APIs using type-safe client? The way provided is via client credentials. Is there any plan to support principal propagation in the future?

https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/clients/scp-workflow-rest-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the Principal Propagation Authentication flow to call the Workflow service while using the type-safe workflow client.

However, you cannot use the `ScpCfServiceDestinationLoader` to create the destination [programmatically](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/clients/scp-workflow-rest-api/#create-destination) in this case. Currently, we only support client credentials flow with the loader.

Instead, you should create a destination in BTP(CF) with OAuth2UserTokenExchange authentication type and then subsequently use `DestinationAccessor` to [fetch](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/clients/scp-workflow-rest-api/#create-destination) this destination.

We are evaluating options to extend the `ScpCfServiceDestinationLoader` API to support other authentication types but have not planned this feature yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This has changed with [Cloud SDK version 4.7.0](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes#new-functionality). You can now use `AuthenticationType.OAUTH2_USER_TOKEN_EXCHANGE` with `ScpCfServiceDestinationLoader`.